# How to encode Text with php to htmlentities.?

Tags: php, html, encode, html-entities

```
<div id="userpost">
<?php echo $txt; ?>
</div>

<?php $txt="yeah yeah"; ?>
```

I want the echo on the div to be the normal text but if you look at the source it would be something like this

```
&#89;&#101;&#97;
```

Comment: Not sure about your server setup, but mine wouldn't response to <php>...perhaps you meant <?php   ??

Comment: is that source code or source in the browser? Check the encoding of the file

Comment: `htmlentities($txt);` maybe ?

Comment: As long as it's being displayed correctly as html, don't worry about the source. Can you provide us link to the live site for testing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this would help you

```
<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; 
?>
```

for detail

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: yes something like that but i don't want the html tags to be encoded only the text inside it "test" i had more description on my question but don't know what happened sorry for the confusion. here is an example http://labs.net63.net/